# How dose persp define ticks? Especially how persp decide how many ticks and which tick delta are used?

Tags: r, perspective

Hy there,

I use `persp` for a 3D-Plot and i am try to find out how `persp` define the ticks when the parameter `ticktype="detailed"` is set.
I want to draw lines into the box around a surface corresponding to the ticks. Up till now, frist I draw  the surface without any labels and axes and add all lines and axes afterwords. To make it clear what I have done -> example code:

```
z <- matrix(rep(1:10, each=10), nrow=10, ncol=10)
x.axis <- 1:nrow(z)
y.axis <- 1:ncol(z)
max.y <- max(y.axis)

# Drawing the surface without the axes and no lines on the surface
pmat <- persp(z = z, x = x.axis, y = y.axis ,
              lphi = 100, phi = 25, theta = -30,
              axes=F,
              border = NA,  # no lines on the surface
              col="deepskyblue",
              expand = 0.5,  
              shade = 0.65)
```

Now I add the the lines on the surface with different color and the axes with ticks and labels:

```
par(new=T)
pmat <- persp(z = z, x = x.axis, y = y.axis ,
              lphi = 100, phi = 25, theta = -30,
              ticktype = "detailed", 
              expand = 0.5, 
              cex.lab=0.75, 
              col=NA, 
              border="grey80")
par(new=F)
```

To get lines on the box around the surface I use the following:

```
for (z_high in c(2,4,6,8)) {
  lines(trans3d(x.axis, max.y, z_high, pmat) , col="black", lty=3)
}
```

As you can see, I use a own defined vector `c(2,4,6,8)` which represents the z-values for the box lines in the back. If the input surface now changes, I have to adapted this vector by my own. Is there a way to get the ticks for all axes in the `persp` plot? Did anyone know how `persp` define the ticks?

Comment: **Found one soloution***: It seems that the function 'pretty' is used to calculate the ticks. So my solution now is to use this function for setting the lines.